# How to import appropriately

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been wondering for a long time how to appropriately import in Python, in relation to the way I'm going to explain now:

Imagine I've got two modules built by myself, `modulea` and `moduleb`, and have a last one which uses both the `modulea` and `b`, so `modulec`.

Furthermore, `modulea` uses `moduleb`.

The modules are all one-file, which form part of a big module which has got its own `__init__.py` file.

```
+ My project
-
-> modulea.py
-> moduleb.py
-> modulec.py
-> __init__.py # Here I import modulea, b, c.
-> main_module.py # This is were I do all the hardcore.
```

I've created a file for importing all the modules I need, instead of importing them one by one in each script, and to know if I have already imported it, I would have to check file for file if I have already imported that or not.

I could simply declare, as you have been saying below in the comment box, the required modules in each module, but I think that's not practical and it's easier to import them all only in one file.

Tell me if this is a good practice or not.

If I import

```
import modulea
import moduleb
import modulec
```

It won't work (`ImportError`) because `modulea` does not implicitly import `moduleb` inside the code, and it is imported before than the module it requires (`b`)

If I did

```
import moduleb
import modulea
import modulec
```

I guess they will work because since the runnning script already imports `moduleb` before `a`, it should also be accessible to `a` and not only to the running script; and the same I guess it happens with `modulec`.

Supposing this is true, which I think indeed, will it work if the import were done in only one line? Are the modules imported and included into the script one by one or are they rather imported altogether and them enabled for use, after the statement finishes (the one-line import call)?

```
import moduleb, modulea, modulec
```

And if it does, does it shorten too much the processing time of the code, or is it basically the same, despite the aesthetic matter?

Comment: The big problem seems to be your modules depend on each other, but don't import each other! `modulea` should `import moduleb` and `modulec` should `import modulea, moduleb`. Then you should import all of them `import modulea, moduleb, modulec` in your final code!

Comment: Can you be clearer why the first solution doesn't work? If `modulea` needs `moduleb` it should import it itself.

Comment: I really don't understand the ImportError. Each module defines its dependencies, in your case `C` needs `A` and `B`. At `C` level, you don't care about what `A` and `B` need, unless you made the mistake of defining a circle dependency.

Comment: @FrancisColas because I have created a file for importing all the modules I need, instead of importing them one by one in each script, which may cause Python importing them twice, and to avoid this I would have to check file for file if I have already imported that or not.

Comment: @Malonge I have just explained up there why I am doing that.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde, each module MUST define its own dependencies. When you import it, it has to work without taking into account how it was loaded. Moreover, Python **does not load twice** the same module.

Comment: @ikaros45 sorry if I haven't been clear enough, I hope my comment there has made myself a bit clearer.

Comment: @ikaros45 I know it doesn't load it twice, but I won't repeat the same lines of code in each module. I think it is not practical at all.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde Regardless of what you think is practical, that's how code is maintained. If `modulec` needs `modulea` and `moduleb`, it needs to import them in its `__init__.py`

Comment: Sorry. I have been mistaking this. They are actually "one-file modules". They are only one file from the same full project which has its own `__init__.py` file.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde: You need to define a package's dependencies inside itself, which means you will need to reuse the "import module" commands multiple times.  Classes/objects are meant to be re-usable and self-contained.  Imagine needing to remember to `import sys`, `import errno`, and `import stat as st` every time you wanted to also `import os`.  _THAT_ is impractical.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde, I think you are missing the point that each module in python is an isolated namespace. Simplifying it a lot: inside of a module, only what you imported is available, plus built-ins. And this is auwesome.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde, do not import anything in `__init__.py` unless you are offering a public API of a package. It creates weird dependencies.

Comment: Ok thank you for pointing that out. @ikaros45 I didn't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overthinking way too much.

Each module must be "self contained" in the sense that itself satisfies its dependencies. If `modulea` needs `moduleb`, you do

```
# modulea.py
import moduleb
```

Then `moduleb` has to import its dependencies, if any:

```
# moduleb.py
import json  # for instance
```

And finally `modulec` needs `modulea` and `moduleb`, you just import them:

```
# modulec.py
import modulea
import moduleb  # <-- actually this import does not reload the moduleb, since it was already loaded in modulea, and it was cached.
```

There is nothing more about this.

And if you just need a function from a module, you can just import it into the namespace like this.

```
from moduleb import my_cool_function
```

Just as style convention, you should do each import in a new line:

```
import json
from moduleb import my_cool_function
from moduleb import another_not_so_cool_function
```

Comment: Cool, so that's what I wanted to say, that they are cached. That's why I said I could import them in only one file. But regarding to your explanation, I won't care anymore about this.

Comment: As I commented in your message, modules are namespaces. Only what is imported is available, everything is explicit. In other languages, like PHP, what you import is "globally global", which produces crappy code hard to maintain with non-explicitly over-polluted namespaces. This is a huge win of python: you can (in general) trust what you see.

Answer (score 2):

According to the python [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should use an import statement for each individual module. It will also tell you everything else you need to know about the conventions surrounding importing modules.

```
import moduleb
import modulea
import modulec
```

Also, as some of the commenters have indicated, you don't seem to be importing these modules properly within each script, thus creating errors here in this script.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of your imports into one place if you'd like.

myproject/internal.py

```
from moduleb import *
from modulea import *
from modulec import *
```

Now, your other modules can just import it

myproject/modulec.py

```
from internal import *
```

Although its usually preferable to import everything in the module that uses it, there are conditions where that is not desirable. I have a project with many small scripts that test product functionality. It would be a bother to have lots of imports in each of them.

Comment: Exactly ! That's what I was trying to say! Lots of small scripts! Thank you now I feel I was doing right

Comment: You were not doing right. Stay away from this if you want to write professional python code. Read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports on wild card imports.

Comment: @ikaros45 - don't be stupid. This and other more radical approaches are perfectly acceptable in domain-specific programming. `from os import *` is a bad idea but when the import module is created specifically to give you a well-defined environment, its fine. In my case, people can easily crib existing short scripts to build functionality and it works great.

Comment: @tdelaney In my years of programming in python, I have found only two good uses for `from x import *`: 1) working on the python console, 2) for settings files, where you want to override local variables with values optionally defined in another module. If I want to "create an environment" I import the module (e.g. `import tools`) and access its members when needed. It gets horribly tricky when you import multiple modules wildcard, and if those modules are using wildcards as well: their garbage cascades into your NS, and even maybe somebody overwrote some built-in.

Comment: @ikaros45 -sounds like you haven't been very good at using the tools available to you. That's kinda sad. You mention settings files, which would be a good domain-specific example. Another one is THE ONE I DESCRIBED SPECIFICALLY. Stop calling me unprofessional just because you can't figure out good ways to use the tool.

Comment: @ikaros45 - I grepped `import \*` in /usr/lib/python2.7 just for fun... I got 1760 hits. Looks like there are a lot of unprofessional hacks out there!

Comment: @tdelaney, my experience with `*` has been more of a headache than anything else, and I have trouble thinking of situations where a qualified import does not do the trick. However, I know that I don't know everything, so if you could provide some concrete examples of what you mean, I would be really grateful. Thanks in advance. PS: there is bad code in the standard libraries as well, that does not tell me too much.